# Certain rules only take effecton update in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I doing this funcationly where the user can update the discription and the image, but i also i want to allow the user if he doesnt choose an image the previous one will stay the same. and it is giveing me that i an not be left empty, now i know its because of the rules but i have tried to make rules just for update but it doesnt seem to work.

Here is the rules in the model

```
return array(
        array('description,imageUrl', 'required', 'on'=>'create'),
        array('imageUrl','file','types'=>'jpg,gif,png'),
        array('description','required', 'on'=>'update'),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('id, description', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
```

And in my actionUpdate controller i have the following.

```
    $model=$this->loadModel($id);
    $model->setScenario('update');


    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['DestinationWedding']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['DestinationWedding'];
        if(!empty($_POST['DestinationWedding']['imageUrl'])){
            //Generating a new file name
            $fileName = mt_rand();
            //Assging the super gloabn array file
            $uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'imageUrl');
            //Check if the name is taken or not
            $checkName = DestinationWedding::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('imageUrl'=>$fileName));

            while(!empty($checkName)){
                $fileName = mt_rand();
                $checkName = DestinationWedding::model()->findAllAttributes(array('imageUrl'=>$fileName));
            }

            //Removeing the old image
            unlink(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/images/upload/destinationWeddings/'.$model['imageUrl']);
            $model->imageUrl = $fileName;
        }

        $valid = $model->validate();

        if($valid){
            if($model->save()){
                //Moveing the uploaded file
                $uploadedFile->saveAs('images/upload/destinationWeddings/'.$fileName);
                //Seeting a new session showing the user successful message
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('succcess','Wedding is updated successfully');
                $this->redirect(array('admin'));
            }else{
                //Setting a new session shwoing the user error message
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error','An error has occured');
            }
        }

    }

    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
```

MY actionCreate is the following

```
$model=new DestinationWedding;
        $model->setScenario = 'create';

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['DestinationWedding']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['DestinationWedding'];
            //Assinging the super golbal array File
            $uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'imageUrl');

            do{
                //Generating a new file name
                $fileName = mt_rand();
                //Check if the name is taken or not
                $checkName = DestinationWedding::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('imageUrl'=>$fileName));
            }while(!empty($checkName));

            $model->imageUrl = $fileName;

            if($model->save()){
                //Moveing the upload file
                $uploadedFile->saveAs("images/upload/destinationWeddings/".$fileName);
                //Setting a new session showing the user successful message
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('success',"File uploaded Successfully");
            }else{
                //Setting a new session showing the user errror message
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('eroor','File was not uploaded Successfully');
            }
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
```

So what i want extly is

- Ability to change the image if the user uplaods an image
- Validate the file
- If left empty no error is given previous image is used

Answer (score 0):

Assuming rest of the code does what you need, you can update your code like the following. Your model rules should be like:

```
return array(
        array('description, imageUrl', 'required','create'),
        array('imageUrl','file','types'=>'jpg,gif,png'),
        array('description','required', 'on'=>'update'),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('id, description', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
);
```

In the rules above make `description` and `imageUrl` required **ONLY** on create scenario.

And change your controller action to:

```
$model=$this->loadModel($id);
$model->setScenario('update');
// Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
// $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

if(isset($_POST['DestinationWedding']))
{

    $uploadedFile = null;
    $model->attributes=$_POST['DestinationWedding'];
    if(!empty($_POST['DestinationWedding']['imageUrl'])){
        //Generating a new file name
        $fileName = mt_rand();
        //Assging the super gloabn array file
        $uploadedFile = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'imageUrl');

        if($uploadedFile){
            //Check if the name is taken or not
            do{
                $checkName = DestinationWedding::model()->findAllAttributes(array('imageUrl'=>$fileName));
                $fileName = mt_rand();
            }while(!empty($checkname));

            //Removeing the old image
            unlink(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/images/upload/destinationWeddings/'.$model['imageUrl']);
            $model->imageUrl = $fileName;
        }
    }

    $valid = $model->validate();

    if($valid){
        if($model->save()){
            //Moveing the uploaded file
            if($uploadedFile)
                $uploadedFile->saveAs('images/upload/destinationWeddings/'.$fileName);
            //Seeting a new session showing the user successful message
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('succcess','Wedding is updated successfully');
            $this->redirect(array('admin'));
        }else{
            //Setting a new session shwoing the user error message
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error','An error has occured');
        }
    }

}

$this->render('update',array(
    'model'=>$model,
));
```

In the action you check for `$uploadedFile` instance, if an instance exists then upload the file and update the database otherwise leave it. I have changed your while loop to do while, which will makes it run at least one time.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the do while dont know why i didnt do it like that, also when i put create inside therules and go o nthe admins page it gives me an error CRequiredValidator.0 how can i fix this, this error happens even when i go on the create page.

Comment: Post your `actionCreate` code then I will be in good position to answer that. One thing more you don't need to validate the model because `$model->save();` does that for you. If you want to bypass validate then you just do `$model->save(false);`

Comment: I have update the question and added the create, i set a scenario to the create function and added to the rules but still takes effect on the update.

Comment: The right way to set a model's scenario is `$model->setScenario('create');` also just check the scenario by `$model->getScenario();` to be sure.

Comment: Still same problem im check if it because of the file validation, the scenarios are set right.

Comment: By the way when you create a model object like `$model = new DestinationWedding;` it automatically gives it a "create" scenario. You can do it in your action as well just put `echo $model->getScenario();` before `$this->render(....);` or even put `print_r($model);` before `$this->render(...);` you will be able to see all the properties of the model.

Comment: Okay i have set teh filetype rules to the create only, now i do validation on the update manly inside the controller, or is there a better way?

Comment: You don't need to do any validation yourself at least in this case because you already defined rules for model validations. When you call `$model->save();` validation is automatically performed according to your set rules. Why you want to do it yourself. You can override the messages if you want, by using the `message` property of `CValidator`. Example will be like `array('imageUrl','file','types'=>'jpg,gif,png','message'=>'Only jpeg, gif, png images are allowed'),`.

Comment: No because i had to do the validation rule on the create xcenario only because that was holding be back on leavein the imagefield empty in the update, that is why.